# Regular expression to remove all non-alphanumeric characters except $

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

Fairly new to regular expressions. I want to be able to remove all non-alphanumeric characters besides $.

So for the string like "I am here $today#", the result should be "I am here $today"

I have tried this already with no luck.

```
   [^a-zA-Z\\s$] and [$^a-zA-Z\\s] and [^a-zA-Z$\\s]
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to reassign the replacement. Most likely your [issue](http://ideone.com/ggtPNw) ...

Comment: Please edit your question to include the java code which is trying to perform this regex operation.

Answer (score 4):

```
String regex = "[^a-zA-Z\\s$]";
String string = "I am here $today#";

string = string.replaceAll(regex, "");

System.out.println(string); // I am here $today
```

This is working just fine...

Comment: That also gets rid of whitespace.

Comment: Me running this exact code says that it works fine. Have you tested or are you saying this just by looking at the code?

Comment: Ah, my bad. IntelliJ "helpfully" added extra slashes to yours when I copy and pasted it in. This works fine. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

This might help, Use:

```
replaceAll("[^\\w\\s\\$]", "");
```

\w is short for [a-zA-Z_0-9]